# How do I convert YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS to std::chrono::system_clock::time_point?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm obtaining YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS components from an offboard real time clock chip. I want to convert this to a `std::chrono::system_clock::timepoint` so that I may obtain the seconds since the Epoch and update the operating system's time.

I would like to use [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant)'s proposed [date](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html) library to perform this conversion.

I would intuitively do something like this:

```
date::year_month_day ymd = ...;
date::time_of_day tod = ...;
auto sysTime = date + tod;
```

but I don't see an appropriate `operator+` overload for this. Am I missing something?

Another use case for this type of conversion is to convert a calendar date and time into a `std::chrono::timepoint` that I can pass to [boost::asio::steady_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/steady_timer.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically a `time_of_day` is just used for formatting a duration into `hh:mm:ss.fff` for output.  But it is possible to turn a `time_of_day` back into a `std::chrono::duration`:

```
auto tod = make_time(hours{17} + minutes{16} + seconds{45});  // time_of_day
auto d = seconds(tod);                                        // seconds
```

In C++14 I would’ve used the more concise:  `17h + 16min + 45s`, but as you mentioned you were in C++11, I’ll stick to C++11 code.

A `year_month_day` can be converted into a `sys_days` with:

```
auto ymd = jul/29/2015;
auto dp = sys_days{ymd};
```

And a `sys_days` is nothing but a `system_clock::time_point` but with a resolution of `days` instead of `microseconds` or `nanoseconds`.

Then you can add a `sys_days` and `duration` and assign that to a `system_clock::time_point`.  Putting it all together:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
   using namespace date;
   using namespace std::chrono;
   auto ymd = jul/29/2015;
   auto tod = make_time(hours{17} + minutes{16} + seconds{45});
   system_clock::time_point tp =  sys_days(ymd) + seconds(tod);
}
```

In this simplified example there is no need to go through `time_of_day`, and you could just stay with `duration`s:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
   using namespace date;
   using namespace std::chrono;
   auto ymd = jul/29/2015;
   system_clock::time_point tp = sys_days(ymd)
                               + hours{17} + minutes{16} + seconds{45};
}
```

The main thing to remember is that `sys_days` is just a coarse `system_clock::time_point`, and when you convert to that from a `year_month_day`, then you are completely in the `std::chrono` system and can do anything you want with `time_point`s and `duration`s from there.

Comment: `auto ymd = jul/29/2015;` What is this monstrosity :(

Comment: It's no monstrosity, it's an unambiguous date literal. If you want to be more ISO-8601-like, you can use 2015_y/7/29 instead.

Too bad 2015_y/09/29 will not work, whereas 2015_y/07/29 will. ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  I went with one of the three orderings used globally that I was comfortable with.  Please use whichever one you're comfortable with as Ville demonstrates. :-)

Comment: @VilleVoutilainen: It's unambiguous in this form, yes, but I thought we'd all agreed ages ago that m/d/y in any form is silly, dangerous and confusing in the general case. Even when you've disambiguated one of the components! Let's stick with y/m/d or d/m/y or y-m-d eh ;p Not too familiar with these new date literals; they look error-prone at first glance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country for "date endian" that peoples of this planet use.  Also see http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html for explanations concerning the error-prone-ness of these date literals.  Specifically, this library is designed to catch these types of errors at compile time.  Additionally, `operator-()` is not used for this purpose, because it could introduce run-time errors too easily when coding date arithmetic.  `operator/()` has the right precedence and syntax to avoid such errors.

Comment: Additionally, the `y/m/d` syntax is optional.  There is a traditional type-safe constructor syntax available if you wish to use it ... all described at http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html .

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Wow, yes, I am well aware of international differences in date notation, thank you. By "we" I was referring to all sensible programmers with whom I've spoken on the matter in the past. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Ok.  Please feel free to download date.h at https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h and run it through a conforming C++11 or C++14 compiler.  If you find any way to create a date that you believe error prone (i.e. a programmer mistake the compiler should catch at compile time, but doesn't), just let me know and I'll see what I can do about it.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Ehm I never claimed you could make a program with it that wouldn't do what you wrote. I even said "it's unambiguous in this form, yes". I'm talking about the human aspect here.

Comment: Also I only just noticed that this is a library of yours rather than Boost or stdlib. Didn't mean to position my views as an attack.

Comment: Understood, no problem.  I'm in the mode of collecting feedback and constructive criticism in order to make the lib more bullet proof.  So shoot some bullets at it.  It needs testing. :-)